# How to request url with authorized token through API

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-applications

I am trying to develop a web-app based on girder platform (a data management platform). During development, I get some problem confused me for a long time. Let me briefly explain my work and if anything I understand worry, please point it out coz I just start.

The thing is that,

In the font end I am using AMI(a javascript library) to deal with image virtualization, and the way is to tell (make a request to girder server) AMI the URL address which contains image to display as attachment. (e.g.`http://girderDomain:port/api/v1/file/imageID/download?contentDisposition=attachment` API of girder)

When this URL does not have any permission, everything works fine. When it needs permission (which is a `token` generated when authorized user login), purely URL does not work, so I was trying to use ajax to make a request with requestHeader(`token`) something like below:

```
$.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'http://girderDomain:port/api/v1/file/imageWithPermissionID/download?contentDisposition=attachment',
                crossDomain:true,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend:function(xhr){
                 //   xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "*");
                  //  xhr.setRequestHeader("girderToken", token);
                },
                success:function (d,s,xhr) {}
});
```

Although I still get some error not solving yet, but ajax is the only way that in my mind.

and the whole process is like pseudocode below:

```
//***AMI***//
var t2 = ["imageID",....];    //////No permission need image
files = t2.map(function(v) {
            return 'http://girderDomain:port/api/v1/file/' + v+'/download?contentDisposition=attachment';
         });
AMI.display(files)
```

As you can see no permission image display is simple and easy to do, and with permission image through ajax request would be something like:

```
   //***ajax to download permission file first***//
    $.ajax({
       //url:'http://girderDomain:port/api/v1/file/imageWithPermissionID/download?contentDisposition=attachment'
       //set requestHeader("girderToken",token);
       //success:function(){
       //download this permission file to request domain tempFolder as A
}
    });
/***AMI***/
var t2 = ["A"];
files = t2.map(function(v) {
            return 'http://requestDomain/tempFolder/A';
         });
AMI.display(files);
```

and that looks stupid, so I am wondering does anyone have any idea to request a file with permission, like maybe save `token` in cookie or session and using some way to make request with cookie or session, or any other new methods, frameworks.

Since I just start that kind of client-server development, any help truly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if you the web service uses JWT to generate tokens?

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: @GrahamS. Thank you for reply, so base on girder ( that data management platform), the token is made from: first base-64 encode the string for example "john:hello" which yields "am9objpoZWxsbw==" and then take the base-64 encoded value and pass it via the `Girder-Authorization` header through their auth API if it is correct a JSON document will be return and  from which I can extract the authentication token

Comment: @MMzztx Good to know. Have you tried setting the header then as `xhr.setRequestHeader('Girder-Authorization', token)` instead of `xhr.setRequestHeader('girderToken', token)`?

Comment: @apokryfos Hi apokryfos, not the error matters, for example, ajax will return  a string base response which I should convert it and download first then display, it is complicated. So what I am wondering is what kind of general process or method developer use to deal with that permission request issue coz I only know ajax, my knowledge is too narrow so any new idea would be perfect

Comment: @MMzztx Actually, I was looking at the docs, it perhaps add this as your header may work: `Girder-Authorization: Basic am9objpoZWxsbw==`. So in your javascript it would translate to `xhr.setRequestHeader('Girder-Authorization', 'Basic ' + token)`. I think you need to add the `Basic ` part before your token, and don't forget the white space. Let me know if that helps. http://girder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer-cookbook.html

Comment: @GrahamS. Yes, I did that for login section and works like a charm, so the problem is not that ajax process goes worry, is that I think ajax may not be a good way to my work (coz, it needs to request->convert request string to download(store) in client-side server->AMI call that do not need permission url), so I am wondering maybe you guys experts use other convenient method to deal with that kind issues. ( maybe like I mention save in session)